# elasticsearch - doc values on timestamp field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have memory problems with aggregation  queries.
my elastic version is 1.3.2
I tired to define _timestamp as doc value ,
but when  I checked the mapping I can see it didn't work
It didn't happen in other fields.
Is there any known issue with timestamp field and doc values?

Lib

Comment: Please share your mapping

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this mapping?

```
{
  "tweet" : {
    "_timestamp" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "format" : "YYYY-MM-dd"
    }
  }
```

I'm using specified version (13.2). I set up custom date field in my project like this and it's worked for me:

```
PUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/a252e39969665bb4d065/' -d
'{
    "a252e39969665bb4d065": {
       "mappings": {
            "_default_": {
                "properties": {
                    "createdDate": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Please, note that i'm using default mapping here (default mapping for all types in index). You can use specified type in an index by replacing "*default*" in mapping.